# NServiceBus sending information when a subscriber subscribes

Tags: c#, .net, nservicebus

I'm just getting started with NServiceBus and I've got a very basic implementation up and running - much like the PubSub sample application.

What I want to do is to send some information when a subscriber subscribes.

For example, lets say I have a database with products that are categorized. My publisher will check the database every N seconds and will send messages when a new product is added to the database.

But each subscriber is only interested in a particular category and I want to send that category when they subscribe so that the publisher knows the check the database for new products in that category.

The categories are dynamic, so I can't create different messages for the different categories. So for that reason I assume that all the subscribers have to subscribe to the same published `IMessage`.

*NOTE: I do also wish to use this information to then filter the messages NServiceBus sends to subscribers, but I thought I would [post that as a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592556/nservicebus-filtering-messages-to-subscribers).*

Comment: I have a solution for that, refer to this post: I have a solution for that, refer to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6484251/what-is-the-best-way-to-route-nservicebus-messages-to-specific-clients/6763698#6763698

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement the IAuthorizeSubscriptions interface to get a callback at the publisher when a subscriber requests to subscribe. If you wanted to include some additional meta-data in the subscription request, you'll need to use Bus.OutgoingHeaders - then you can look at that info at the publisher and decided what to do with it.

Comment: Thanks Udi, I'll look at doing that tonight. Could you point me towards any doucmentation or examples of doing what you suggest? Also, do you have anything you can weigh in on my other question? Appreciate it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with NServiceBus for quite some time but I don't think NServiceBus has any events to notify you when a subscription has taken place.

Be that as it may I think you may be approaching your solution on a level that is too fine.

You usually subscribe to events that the business is typically interested in.  In your case when a new product is added.  A simpler solution would be to simply subscribe to say a `ProductAddedEvent` and have your subscriber ignore any messages that it is not interested in.

Self-promotion warning! :) --- I have a FOSS ESB available here (still CTP): http://shuttle.codeplex.com/

We make use of pipelines for various parts of the bus and you have given me an idea to include a `SubscriptionRequested` event on the `StartupPipeline`.

Comment: Thanks Eben. Unfortunately my example was just that, an example. The actual problem is a lot more complicated, I just used the example to simplify what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Maybe you could provide more information in your question.  You may have a situation where you need to implement a router of some kind as opposed to pub/sub.